# How to add specific row from datagridview to listbox in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, listbox

When clicking a button, I want the values from a specific row from my `DataGridView` to be placed in the `ListBox`. For example, when pressing the Budgie button, I want all the details about the Budgie, which is in row 1, placed in the `ListBox` (it's so I can calculate costs) However, when I press the button all that shows up in the `ListBox` is `DataGridViewRow { Index=1 }` What do I need to change to show the values rather than that?

```
Private Sub btnBudgie_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBudgie.Click
  Me.lstSales.Items.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(1))
End Sub
```

Comment: Specify _specific_ in "specific row". I doubt that it's always the second row(`Rows(1)`), is it?

Comment: Specific row as in I want it to be the budgie row, sorry I'm a complete beginner at this. It should always be the second row I think?

Comment: The database is product details for a pet shop, so one of the products is a budgie. The form I'm creating is like a sales page, instead of scannign a barcode a button is pressed for the product the customer is buying, so when Budgie is pressed, I want the details of the budgie to come up in the listbox

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if you select the whole row:

```
Dim Item As String = ""
    Try
        Dim c As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells.Count - 1

        If c <= 0 Then
            c = 0
        End If

        For x = 0 To c
            Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(x)

            If x = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells.Count - 1 Then
                Item = Item & cell.Value
            Else
                Item = Item & cell.Value & " - "
            End If
        Next

        ListBox1.Items.Add(Item)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An error occured. Have you selected a whole row?" & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but is there a way to do it without selecting the row? I don't want the datagridview to be visible, so can I like link only one row to the button? Because I have a button for each product

Comment: Why do you even use a DataGridView then? Why not just a List(Of String)?

Comment: I don't know, just trying to do a school project but never done any coding before..

Comment: Wasn't this marked as answer before or am I just thinking of something else?

Comment: Huh? What do you mean?

Comment: I thought the question was marked as answer... But I may be remembering wrong. :)